# Title and author in header without fancyhdr

Tags: header-footer

I'm trying to have the author names and title appear on alternating pages, respectively, in the center of the header. In addition I would like to have even numbered pages on the left in the header and odd numbered pages on the right in the header - Starting from page 2. I would like to avoid using the package fancyhdr as I do no want any line separating the header from the body.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have several possibilities:

1) Using [`titleps`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titleps)

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage{titleps}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newpagestyle{mystyle}{
\sethead[\thepage][\Author][]{}{\Title}{\thepage}
}
\pagestyle{mystyle}

\author{First Author \and Second Author}
\title{The title}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\Author{First Author---Second Author}
\let\Title\@title
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\lipsum[1-20]

\end{document}
```

2) Using [`fancyhdr`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) (with `\renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}` there will be no rule in the header):

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[CE]{\Author}
\fancyhead[CO]{\Title}
\renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\author{First Author \and Second Author}
\title{The title}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\Author{First Author---Second Author}
\let\Title\@title
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\lipsum[1-20]

\end{document}
```

3) Without packages:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\author{First Author \and Second Author}
\title{The title}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\Author{First Author---Second Author}
\let\Title\@title
\def\ps@mystyle{%
      \let\@oddfoot\@empty\let\@evenfoot\@empty
      \def\@evenhead{\makebox[0pt][l]{\thepage}\hfill\Author\hfill}%
      \def\@oddhead{\hfill\Title\hfill\makebox[0pt][l]{\thepage}}%
      \let\@mkboth\markboth}
\makeatother
\pagestyle{mystyle}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\lipsum[1-20]

\end{document}
```

#### Addendum:

In comments, it has been requested a solution *without* using the `twoside` class option:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\author{First Author \and Second Author}
\title{The title}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\Author{First Author---Second Author}
\let\Title\@title
\def\ps@mystyle{%
      \let\@oddfoot\@empty\let\@evenfoot\@empty
      \def\@oddhead{%
       \ifodd\value{page}\relax
          \hfill\Title\hfill\makebox[0pt][l]{\thepage}%
      \else
          \makebox[0pt][l]{\thepage}\hfill\Author\hfill%
      \fi%
      }%
      \let\@mkboth\markboth}
\makeatother
\pagestyle{mystyle}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\lipsum[1-20]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, is there any way of doing the above without having [twoside] after document class?

Comment: @nonameswereavailable `twoside` allows to alternate the information on even and odd pages. I updated my answer providing a possible solution without this option (the last example code in my answer). Just out of curiosity, why don't you want to use this option?

Comment: The [twoside] shift the body slightly to the left or right, depending on whether you're on an even or odd page. I need the body of my text to be uniform, while having the alternating headers. I thought it would be easier modifying the header as opposed to introducing new constraints for the body. I very much appreciate your help.

Comment: @nonameswereavailable you can keep the `twoside` option and use the `centering` option for `geometry`, as in `\documentclass[twoside]{article}\usepackage[centering]{geometry}`.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina, is it possible to avoid requiring the `\newcommand\Author{First Author---Second Author}` command and address the string in `\author{name}`? I am hoping that it is possible to pull the name directly without the extra needed step. I have a style file and would like to include the author name in the fancyhr usage. I tried `\author{name1}
\newcommand\Author{\author}` in the .tex file but it does not compile

Comment: @GonzaloMedina with regards to your final suggestion (the Addendum); firstly thank you very much for it! Secondly, how would I make all the headers full in capitals with the first letter of each word larger than the rest of the word?