# How to access the author name and title from a style file to be placed inside the header?

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, author

I am trying to make a style file where all of the preamble commands are set in the style file except the need for the title and author name to be defined in the .tex file. The style file places into the header the title and author name. I am using the approach outlined in the answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/129968/1026), for the case using `fancyhdr`. This does work by putting the following lines into my preamble:

```
\title{My Title} 
\author{My Name}
\makeatletter
\let\Title\@title
\newcommand\Author{My Name}
\makeatother
```

Which allows me to put the following into my style file `mystyle.sty`:

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[LE,LO]{\vspace{1pt}\textcolor{gray}{\Title }}
\fancyhead[RE,RO]{\vspace{1pt}{\Author}}
```

So that I can place into the header the title and author name.

The functionality is fine, and gives the desired results, but I would like to move the lines `\makeatletter`,`\let\Title\@title`,`\newcommand\Author{My Name}`, and `\makeatother` from the .tex file into the .sty file. Is this possible and if yes how can it be done? (it is not a requirement to solely rely on 'fancyhdr')

Comment: If it is your own .sty file, no prolem.  In fact, \maketatletter isn't needed.  Do NOT modify a provided .sty file.  Not only will the modification be lost when you update, it is just plain wrong.

Comment: You could use \csname @title\endcsname inside fancyhdr.

Comment: @JohnKormylo, my own style file; first attempt at doing so.

Comment: Personally, I use \input with a .tex file instead.  MikTeX makes adding .sty files more complicated than .tex files.

Comment: @JohnKormylo, I will consider the `\input`, did not know that was an alternative, since most configurations I have used in the past relied on '\usepackage'. The `title` line you recommended worked great, thanks! Is there an analogous one for the `\author`?

Comment: @JohnKormylo, I just exchanged the 'title' for 'author' and it worked! Could you post your solution as an answer?

Comment: There was a problem when I tried it inside \fancyhead.  It seems \maketitle eats \@title and \@author.

Comment: @JohnKormylo, I have not tried to make a title page. Used it directly. Also, do you have any idea how the '\bibliographystyle' command could be put inside the .sty file?

Comment: You should read more basics before trying to write a package.

Comment: @Johannes_B, I have D. Knuth's book, and am reading through sections, and read through some of the documentation, but some parts of the theory are still not clear to me when I try to apply it. Looking to learn more through practice and seek advice when stuck, which is hopefully useful for someone in the future by having the trouble shooting here

Answer (score 1):

In a `.sty` file, there is no need to use `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` because `@` is already a letter.

If you try to move

```
\let\Title\@title
```

etc. into a `.sty` file, it can not save the title, because the `\title` isn't set yet.

Instead you can patch `\maketitle` to save the author and title for you, so you have to write

```
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\pretocmd\maketitle{%
  \let\Title\@title%
  \let\Author\@author%
}{}
```